# ReferenceError: newFunction is not defined

Tags: angularjs

How to Define a new function in angular can anybody please help me out
My code is like this:

```
var app = angular.module('rtsApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngStorage','ngRoute', 'restangular','timepickerPop', 'ngStomp', 'ngCookies', 'angular-cron-gen','uiSwitch','ngMaterial', 'md.data.table']);

app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    newFunction(RestangularProvider);//I need newFunction here
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({
        "X-API-KEY": "sks@2017",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"

    });
```

Actually I am Getting This Error

> Failed to instantiate module rtsApp due to:
>
> ReferenceError: newFunction is not defined
>
> ```
> at http://localhost:3000/dist/js/scripts.min.js:1738:5
> at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/dist/js/vendor.min.js:82:460)
> at d (http://localhost:3000/dist/js/vendor.min.js:80:333)
> at http://localhost:3000/dist/js/vendor.min.js:80:472
> at q (http://localhost:3000/dist/js/vendor.min.js:46:7)
> at g (http://localhost:3000/dist/js/vendor.min.js:80:234)
> at gb (http://localhost:3000/dist/js/vendor.min.js:84:352)
> at c (http://localhost:3000/dist/js/vendor.min.js:60:57)
> at Wc (http://localhost:3000/dist/js/vendor.min.js:60:370)
> at ye (http://localhost:3000/dist/js/vendor.min.js:59:45)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

try it :-
another scenario is follow below code,

```
'use strict';
var deck = angular.module('app',
        ['ui.router',other lib...]);

angular.module("app").config(["$breadcrumbProvider", "$httpProvider", function ($breadcrumbProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $breadcrumbProvider.setOptions({
            prefixStateName: 'userHome.main',
            template: 'bootstrap3'
        });
        //Do No Remove This Line 
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file and define a module in the file. For example create **globalFunctions.js** and add this file to your `index.html` file with this :

```
<script src="/path/to/file/location/globalFunctions.js"></script>
```

Define a module and also your global functions. like this:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('test', []);
})();

function test() {
    console.log("test");
}
```

Inject it in main app (`app.module.js`) and call it:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('app', [
    'test',
     ...
  ]);

  app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    test();
  });
})();
```

---

**Update**

All files for a simple test:

**app.module.js**

```
(function () {
  var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'global'
  ]);

  app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    test();
  });

})();
```

**test.module.js**

```
(function () {
    angular.module('global', []);
})();

function test() {
    console.log("it is test function here");
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.module.js"></script>
<script src="test.module.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <h2>It is a test</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZCUm0C78gOv7SZbtlBCr?p=preview) provided for my solution

Comment: if i call it in the same file i am getting result, but i need to call the function from another js file.

Comment: These 2 parts of code are in separate files! one is a module from `test.module.js` and one other is in `app.module.js`. You should import script in `index.html` and then inject test in `app.module.js` @SuvinKumar

Comment: also exporting and importing with ES6 would be a good solution to this

Comment: @noobie-php plunker added to answer